# How to reference text Label outside of Form's code?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, forms, visual-c++

Code Sample 1

```
//Set Label.
this->TextLabel1= (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
```

Code Sample 2

```
//When Button Clicked....
TextLabel1->Text = "Button has been pressed";
```

How do I reference (+ change) the Label that has been set, outside the Form's code. Eg. Another cpp or header file?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is break encapsulation, often a bad thing, and set TextLabel1 to public.

Hence

```
private: System::Windows::Forms:Label^ TextLabel1;
```

becomes

```
public: System::Windows::Forms:Label^ TextLabel1;
```

Now you can change TextLabel1 from the calling code:

```
Form1 ^form = gcnew Form1();
form->TextLabel1->Text = "Text has been changed from the outside.";
Application::Run(form);
```